# Mybatis nested one-to-one or one-to-many relations mapping

Tags: nested, mapping, one-to-many, mybatis, one-to-one

I use myBatis to map a simple database (as an example).

It consists of 4 models: **User**, **Car**, **Tariff**, **Insurance**.

**User** has **private List carList** and **private Tariff tariff** and some other fields with getters and setters.

**Car** has **private Insurance insurance** and some other fields with getters and setters.

So I can map only 1st nesting level. I mean i can map **User** and its fields -  **Tariff** and a List of **Cars**. But I can't map **Insurance** field of **Car**. What should I do?

Here is my mapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace = "UserNamespace">
    <resultMap id="resultUser" type="User">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <association property="tariff" column="tariff" select="getTariff" javaType="Tariff"/>
        <collection property="carList" column="id" select="getCars" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Car">
            <id property="id" column="id"/>
            <result property="model" column="model"/>
            <association property="insurance" column="insurance" select="getInsurance" javaType="Insurance"/>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

    <select id = "getAll" resultMap = "resultUser">
        SELECT * FROM carwashservice.users
    </select>

    <select id = "getTariff" parameterType="int" resultType="Tariff">
        SELECT tariffs.description FROM carwashservice.tariffs WHERE tariffs.id = #{id}
    </select>

    <select id = "getCars" parameterType="int" resultType="Car">
        SELECT * FROM carwashservice.cars WHERE cars.user = #{id}
    </select>

    <select id = "getInsurance" parameterType="int" resultType="Insurance">
        SELECT * FROM carwashservice.insurance WHERE insurance.id = #{insurance}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

And my DB:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `carwashservice` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `carwashservice`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cars`;
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insurance` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_idx` (`user`),
  KEY `insurance_idx` (`insurance`),
  CONSTRAINT `user` FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `insurance`;
CREATE TABLE `insurance` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `exp_date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `cars` (`insurance`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tariffs`;
CREATE TABLE `tariffs` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tariff` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tariff_idx` (`tariff`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `tariff` FOREIGN KEY (`tariff`) REFERENCES `tariffs` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get NullPointerException when access to insurance field. Other fields filled with values correctly. Tried to do this through JOIN-select on the full map - that worked perfectly, because JOIN creates one table and mapping becomes simple. But my main question is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the car mapping:
`<collection property="carList" column="id" select="getCars" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="Car" />`

In a separated resultMap:
`<resultMap id="resultCar" type="Car">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="model" column="model"/>
    <association property="insurance" column="insurance" select="getInsurance" javaType="Insurance"/>
</resultMap>`

And reference it from the statement
`<select id = "getCars" parameterType="int" resultMap="resultCar">`

You are using `resultType="Car"`. This is fine for basic mapping, but there is an association with Insurance: this is not basic and require specific mapping.

Furthermore, the *getCars* statement uses its own resultMap, then what you define inside *carList* collection is actually ignored (out of scope). that's why the insurance list is null.

Comment: I will try what you said, but I'm sure - there is no need to create another resultMap. I saw an examples of nested mapping with one result map and one sql-select. For example here: http://www.programering.com/a/MDN5MjMwATg.html

Comment: The example you provide uses a single select with joins. You specified in a previous comment that you have already made that working and you want to use the N+1 select approach instead with _collection **select="getCars"**_

Comment: I'm sorry. Here is what I mean: https://github.com/loiane/ibatis-handling-joins/blob/master/src/com/loiane/data/Blog.xml