# Mybatis - nesting object sin other object

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a following scenario:

```
class A {
   int i;
   int b;
   C c;
   D d;
   F f;
   List <H> elems;
   W w;
}
```

It is working ok - I mean tha mybatis properly mapps fields, I get correct object of `class A`, namely fields `i,b,c,d,f,elems` are initialized.   `w` is not initialized - thats ok, because it shouldnt be.

**Problem**
Get from mybatis object:
A a { i, b, c, d, w {elems, w}}
However, using in resultMap dot notation (something like `<result column = "someColumn" property = "w.elems"/>`) I got `NPE` exception.

To sum up:  The problem is: how to put two object into nested object, during mapping or after mapping - however it should be done immediately after mapping (creating object by mybatis)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dot notation in result map definition.
You have to declare "*nested result maps*", either nested in a single result map or referenced: use *association* and *collection* tags.
Have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41442636)'s code for an example.